# save php session to db (session_set_save_handler)

Tags: php, session

I work in a website and we need to cluster server to have more than 1 computer handling with traffic.
so I need to convert php session (file session) to a db for this cluster work.

I have a simple login file:
check if post user == password, if num rows == 1:

```
$_SESSION['user']=$_POST['user'];
```

my problem starts here, how can I write this USER in my database using session_set_save_handler?
what I need to change get _write work?

```
public function _write($id){
  // Create time stamp
  $data = time();

  // Set query  
  $this->db->query('INSERT INTO sessions (id,user,data) VALUES (:id, :user, :data)');

  // Bind data
  $this->db->bind(':id', $id);
  $this->db->bind(':user', $user);  //how can i get login user?
  $this->db->bind(':data', $data);

  // Attempt Execution
  // If successful
  if($this->db->execute()){
    // Return True
    return true;
  }

  // Return False
  return false;
}
```

DB

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sessions` (
  `id` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `user` varchar(20),
  `data` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: What exactly happens? What's the error?

Comment: The $user variable does not exist in your code.

Comment: i cant get login user to save in my sessions db, i dont know how to send this login username to my function

Comment: $this->db->bind(':user', $_SESSION['user']);

Comment: Why dont you : public function _write($id, $user, $data)  ? As @Heru-Luin says you are missing the variables

Comment: Did you read the manual to understand how "session_set_save_handler" works? Here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php or any tutorials like this one: http://www.sitepoint.com/writing-custom-session-handlers/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, your `_write` function misses second argument, in this case `$user`:

```
function _write($id,$user)
```

that's where your data (contents of `$_SESSION` array) is located. The name `$user` is confusing, it is just any data that is contained in `$_SESSION` array, so it would be better to use for example `$value` name.

Also as id in your session table should be unique, it might not succeed if there is already such session. So in that case you update it with expiration time:

```
if($this->db->execute()){
    return true;
}else{
    $this->db->query('UPDATE sessions SET user=:user, data:data WHERE id=$id');

    $this->db->bind(':access', $access);  
    $this->db->bind(':data', $data);

    $this->db->execute();
}
```

As to the time, it should be expiration time, you better change it to:

`$data = time()+ini_get("session.gc_maxlifetime");`

Comment: oh, so $sessionId has the id from session that is in user browser and my db? and data all other $_SESSION['SOMETHING']?

Comment: yes, this table should have unique id of session, expiration time and value of all `$_SESSION` serialized.

Answer (score 0):

The write function of the session_set_save_handler, accepts two arguments:

```
function write(string $sessionId, string $data)
{
    //$data = serialized presentation of your whole session, including 'user'
    ...
}
```

See [What kind of serialization uses PHP function session_set_save_handler's write function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6674676/what-kind-of-serialization-uses-php-function-session-set-save-handlers-write-fu) For more info

Comment: thank you very much! my problem was in that $data, know i understand it has all session values!